# SQL Server : query for reports

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'll need to create queries for weekly, monthly, yearly payments and which service has more sales.

Here is my SQL code that I wrote for 1 to 30 days payments:

```
SELECT 
    payments_date, payments_amount, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, [payments_date], GETDATE()) AS Diff 
FROM
    dbo.payments
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, payments_date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
ORDER BY
    payments_amount DESC
```

`dbo.treatments` is a different table `dbo.payments` is a different table

The column of `dbo.treatments` is `treatments_name`, columns of `dbo.payments` is `payments_amount`. So I'll need to know which treatment has been sold more..

I don't think you need more details?

**dbo.treatments**

```
treatments_id  
taxes_id  
treatmentstype_id  
treatments_code  
treatments_name  
treatments_price  
treatments_isunitprice  
treatments_mexpiration  
treatments_notes
```

**dbo.payments**

```
payments_id  
patiens_id  
payments_date  
payments_amount  
payments_notes
```

Comment: We need sample data and expected result

Comment: You need to explain what services are and how to see if someone has payed or not, either with sample data or table descriptions.

Comment: I guess there is also a payments_date column since you're using it in your query. How do you connect payments and treatments table, is there a reference in the payments table to the treatments table?

Comment: No it doesnt have any reference, thats why im asking' there are 2 different tables that must bring me a value , i dont know how

Comment: Then please list **all** columns in the `Payments` table and **all** columns in the `Treatments` table

Comment: I assume somehow you know which patient has been given what treatment?

Comment: Wich treatment has be sales more,  and the 2nd question was with  weekly,yearly,monthly, sales

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that answer. My question was in relation to the fact that there is a `patiens_id` in the `Payments` table but no obvious connection to the `Treatments` table

Comment: I think that they have

Comment: But how to write the query for  that option that i asked

Comment: No one will be able to help you when you answer "I think that they have", we can't guess your database structure.

Comment: Patients has relation with  treatments.. !!!!!!!

Comment: ***I'll need to create queries for weekly, monthly, yearly payments*** No 1 query using `group by grouping sets` to handle the different intervals.  and limits for where on the reports.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  
    <service_column_name>, MAX(payments_amount)
from 
    dbo.payments
```

where datediff(day, payments_date, getdate()) between 1 and 30
    group by

For second part of the question assuming payed and not payed are flags:

```
select 
    <service_column_name>, COUNT(payed), COUNT(not_payed)
from 
    dbo.payments
```

where     select
        , MAX(payments_amount)
    from 
        dbo.payments 
where datediff(day, payments_date, getdate()) between 1 and 30
    group by

Comment: I used ur code when i execute i receive this 

Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column 'dbo.payments.payments_date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column 'dbo.payments.payments_date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And treatments_name are a column from dbo.treatments, and payments_amount is in another table dbo.payments

Comment: @Charlie Why do you refuse to improve your question with the requested information, until you do you will not get any qualified answers.

Comment: Know i have write the tables names and columms that i want to know the diff about them

Comment: `HAVING` should *only* be used on **aggregated** columns - when you want to have a condition on a column with `SUM`, `MAX`, `AVG` etc. Here, you really should use `WHERE` instead